# Create UI heavy element on another thread wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

This is the working code(but on UI thread):

```
<ContentControl 
                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" 
                Focusable="True"  
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                Content="{Binding Work}" >
            </ContentControl>
```

This is the code I'm trying to make instead, but it doesn't work: (codebehind)

```
            InitializeComponent();

            var thread = new Thread(
                () =>
                {
                    var a = new ContentControl { Focusable = true, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right };
                    var binding = new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("Work"), };

                    a.SetBinding(ContentProperty, binding);
                    MainGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { MainGrid.Children.Add(a); }));
                }) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
```

My goal is to create a `ConentControl` and place it in the Grid, which is inside a `listview` with multiple `ContentControls`.) The shown solution is crashing because a different thread owns the `MainGrid`.
Anyone got good ideas for this? (would love to do it on another thread because the `ContentControl` is heavy, like 3 sec to create the layout. It's a generic view which creates itself according to parameters.)

**EDIT:**

The main problem is that during creation of these views, my whole application hangs. Which is very unwanted. My goal is to move this workload to another (or multiple) other thread(s).

Comment: You can't create UI elements on a thread other than the UI thread. You can create the data required to create the UI on another thread though. That's what you should be aiming to do. Get all of the you IO done off of the UI thread. That should make the UI build very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the binding to be performed on a different thread by using the `IsAsync` property.

```
Content="{Binding Work, IsAsync=True}"
```

This will perform the binding to `Work` on a new thread and the content will be populated when it's done. You won't need to bother with your code-behind stuff.

You can find a nice tutorial of it in action [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFAsyncBinding.aspx).

Comment: It does the loading Async yeah. BUT the rendering of my view still uses a hell lot of time, which makes my whole application stop for some seconds..

Comment: If the rendering is due to a bunch of bindings which take a long time, then `IsAsync` should help to solve that. However, if you are generating your View in code (Which you shouldn't be doing), then you'll need to use some fancy asynchronous task to render it. Could you post your renderer in your original question? It may be possible to convert it to a Custom Control, or a User Control, without having to render it *manually*.

Comment: I'm not sure actually, but I think it's a bunch of bindings.. I'm using a control made by another team. Do I need `IsAsync` on every binding?

Comment: You should only use `IsAsync` where you need it. For example, if you have properties that take a while to load, then it's useful there, otherwise it isn't too important. If you can contact the team, they should be able to tell you if and what properties take a long time to load, and whether it's safe to use `IsAsync` on them. It's hard to advise as I can't see all of your code, but it's a start.